# How to increase the value of a sound file like an uiimagefile

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, image, audio

I have the following piece of code:

.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


-(id) initWithFrame: (CGRect)frame andPosition: (NSInteger)pos andValue: (NSInteger)value {
self = [super initWithFrame: frame];
if (self) {
    self.frontImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:      @"front%ld.png", (long) (value+1)]];
    self.backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back"];


  }
  return self;
 }


@end
```

Ok, seems easy. Just a frame with images. The Images get a value +1. 
But i can't figure it out how to do that with a sound file. i want to "link up" the image and the related sound file. the files have numbers e.g. front1,front2... and the soundless have sound1, sound2...

thanks for help!

EDIT: something like

```
self.audioplayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSURL   alloc] initFileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle]     pathForResource:@"sfx%ld.wav", (long) (value+1)] error:NULL];
```

doesnt work

Comment: `self.audioplayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSURL   alloc] initFileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sfx%ld.wav", (long) (value+1)]] error:NULL];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Following

```
NSString * strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sfx%ld", (long) (value+1)];
NSString * strPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:strName ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL * urlPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strPath];
self.audioplayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlPath error:NULL];
```

Comment: thanks. but here it gets crashed: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
***

Comment: Check value of strName. Is it nil?

Comment: sry my fault, its not crashing any more, was in wrong sample project, hehe... but it plays no sound by clicking on the related image. don't have i to say that he should play the sample by touch?

Comment: Are you calling `[self.audioplayer play];`

Comment: Yes, directly in the initWithFrame Method

Comment: I've posted it as an answer because in comments its too long

Comment: You can edit the question. No need to add this in comment or as answer

Comment: Try this `[self.audioplayer prepareToPlay];
[self.audioplayer play];`

Comment: thank you so much! its working! but one thing isn't nice: when the method flip goes back both sounds are played at the same time

Comment: Before allocating a player, Just stop player and set nil.

Answer (score 0):

`pathForResource` method takes simple NSString, not format. Do this:

```
    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sfx%ld.wav", (long) (value+1)];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:nil];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];
    self.audioplayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url  error:nil];
```

Comment: thank you! but o get an error now:  No visible @interface for 'AVAudioPlayer' declares the selector 'initWithContentsOfURL:' i have imported the "#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>" and a property with "@property (nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioplayer;"

Comment: @vladimir : We have to use `[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlPath error:NULL];`  instead of `[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlPath];`

Answer (score 0):

```
-(id) initWithFrame: (CGRect)frame andPosition: (NSInteger)pos andValue: (NSInteger)value {
self = [super initWithFrame: frame];
if (self) {
    self.frontImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"card-%ld.png", (long) (value+1)]];


    NSString * strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sfx%ld", (long) (value+1)];
    NSString * strPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:strName ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL * urlPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strPath];
    self.audioplayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlPath error:NULL];
    [self.audioplayer play];

}
return self;
}
```

i think i have to say something like button touched or something? or does the audio player inherit that from initwithframe?